# A text file is not read by a Java program in NetBeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans

My Java program only reads a text file fine if its absolute path is indicated as it appears on the file system, f.ex. ="C://textfilename.txt", but does not read it if its name is indicated as "../textFilesFolder/textfilename.txt". The Java program is located in a folder at the same level in SourcePackages as the textFilesFolder.

Is it necessary to configure something in NetBeans for this to work?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your project Properties, then go to the "Sources" category, you can "Add Folder" to your "Source Package Folders". Once you do that, the new directory and the resources in it should be visible in the Projects window. See if that helps.

If not, I wonder if the Working Directory (in the "Run" category of the same project Properties menu) for your project is set incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has fixed the problem.